# How to display long text in jQM listview's <h1> tag?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am making a jQuery mobile and phonegap app. I hava a problem with listviews. They are created dynamically. In these listviews there are h1 tags. And here is the problem. Text is being cut in its 60 or 70% of length and repleced with dots. It's quite annoying, because there is still a lot of space for this text to show. Do you know how to prevent this behaviour?

[image: Example below:]

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Open a developer tool and overrule the corresponding css class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test this in normal browser if can and find which css class is used to render a list, after that change css white-space to normal. Something like this:

```
.ul-li .ui-btn-text a.ui-link-inherit {
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
```

}

change:

```
    white-space: nowrap;
```

to:

```
    white-space: normal;
```